# Good book detailing the security aspects of Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: penetration-test, protocols, active-directory, microsoft

I am attending training later this summer related to AD pentesting. As such, I wanted to ask for book recommendations which detail (in full or in part) the security aspects of Active Directory. The more detailed the better.

Most books I've picked up thus far are much more concerned with administration. I've been having a hard time finding information on specifically the security surrounding AD. How the various components communicate with one-another, NTLM, Kerberos, trusts, etc... Not just how to wire it up but how it ticks.

I should have mentioned that I'm open to all forms of media. I said "book" but videos, blog posts, training courses.... open to it all. Trying not to break the bank but all suggestions are helpful.

I would like to argue that my question was not focused entirely on product recommendations. The truth of the matter is that there appear to be very few knowledge sources that focus on the security of Active Directory. So few that I am having a dilly of a time finding them. Conversely, if I had asked, "What's a great book for administering Active Directory"... well... there's thousands upon thousands of books / videos / training / etc... out there on that topic. I wouldn't even bother asking as I could easily find one for myself.

I would also argue that any information provided here will be relevant for years to come. Understanding Active Directory 2003 is still a great foundation for understanding AD 2016.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here johny.

Comment: Check out the website adsecurity.org

Comment: Well, I did include videos, blog posts, etc... Does that lessen it from a "product recommendation" perspective? I'm only asking this because.... there doesn't seem to be good documentation all in one place. Heck, I would accept a MS whitepaper reference.

Comment: Also, given how Active Directory is an evolving technology I would argue that book recommendations on this topic will not be obsolete quickly. In fact, they will likely be relevant for 5 to 10 years. Same goes for whitepapers, blog posts, videos, etc. My opinion, of course. If you agree with this I would appreciate my question being taken off hold. Thank you.

Comment: Gaius, thank you for the suggestion. Looks to be full of great information which will, no doubt, be relevant for years to come. Cheers.

Comment: Requests for books/sites/videos/etc. are off-topic here. Not only can any one answer become obsolete, but there can be a neverending supply of possible answers, which makes it not a great question type for a Q&A site.

Comment: Hi Johny - I may be wrong, but I think that if you rephrase the question as a more "timeless" question, it's on topic. So instead of "what book should I use", ask "what traits should a good book have". I could be wrong thought. Hope this helps.